# Doubt about Lang's "Elliptic Curves Diophantine Analysis"

Tags: elliptic-curves

I am trying to understand Theorem VII.3.4 of AEC without using formal groups. I am reading then Chapter III.1 in *Elliptic Curves Diophantine Analysis* by Lang. In the proof of theorem 1.3 he says that $t(P)\mid t(p^{m-1}P)$ and I don't understand why. Can you help me?